# Javascript: how to manipulate an array of time ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of time ranges (in string format) like this:

```
["09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00", "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00", "16:00 - 16:30", "17:00 - 17:30"]
```

How to get a new array (or manipulating the starting one) that contains:

- a new compressed time range element if the end time of the first range is equal to the start time of the next range;
- the original time range element if the end time of the first range is different to the start time of the next range;

The result of the above example must be:

```
["09:00 - 11:00", "11:30 - 13:00", "16:00 - 16:30", "17:00 - 17:30"]
```

My attempt:

```
let start = ["09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00", "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00", "16:00 - 16:30", "17:00 - 17:30"]
let compressed = [];
for (let i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
    let currentSlot = start[i];
    let nextSlot = start[i + 1];
    if (currentSlot && nextSlot) {
      let currentSlotStartHour = currentSlot.slice(0, 5);
      let currentSlotEndHour = currentSlot.slice(-5);
      let nextSlotStartHour = nextSlot.slice(0, 5);
      let nextSlotEndHour = nextSlot.slice(-5);
      if (currentSlotEndHour === nextSlotStartHour) {
        // merge slots
        console.log(currentSlotStartHour);
        console.log(currentSlotEndHour);
        console.log(nextSlotStartHour);
        console.log(nextSlotEndHour);
        let compressedSlot = currentSlotStartHour
          .concat(" - ")
          .concat(nextSlotEndHour);
        // add compressed slot
        compressed.push(compressedSlot);
        // remove the next slot
        result.splice(i + 1, 1);
      } else {
        compressed.push(currentSlot);
      }
    }
}
console.log(compressed);
// compressed is: ["09:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 11:00", "11:30 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00", "16:00 - 16:30"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is the array sorted?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: First step: turn the strings into objects, like `"09:00 - 09:30"` becomes `{ start: 540, stop: 570 }` (that's minutes since midnight). Next you need to find pairs where a.stop equals b.start and combine them into a.start & b.stop.

Comment: The array is sorted and I have already tried to iterate over the array with a for loop, take the current range and the next range extracting the end time from the current range and the start time from the next range to made a check.. But I'm missing something.. I edited the question with my attempt..

Comment: `Array.reduce()` can be an starting point... try something and come back with a more accurate question, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Best solution IMO would be to use recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic algorithm is the following:

1. If the accumulator is empty, push the current time slot
2. If it is not empty, compare the last known time slot's end time to the current start time
3. If they are:

   1. not equal, add a new slot to the accumulator
   2. else, update the last known time slot's end time with the current end time

```js
const slots = [
  "09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00",
  "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00",
  "16:00 - 16:30",
  "17:00 - 17:30"
];

const optimizeTimeSlots = (slots, delimiter) => {
  return slots.reduce((acc, slot) => {
    if (acc.length === 0) {
      acc.push(slot);
    } else {
      const curr = slot.split(delimiter);
      const prev = acc[acc.length - 1].split(delimiter);
      if (prev[1] !== curr[0]) {
        acc.push(slot);
      } else {
        prev[1] = curr[1];
        acc[acc.length - 1] = prev.join(delimiter);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(optimizeTimeSlots(slots, ' - '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can remove the main branching-logic by removing the following `if (acc.length === 0) / else` clause and start your accumulator with `[ slots.shift() ]` instead of an empty array.

### Alternatives

You could modify this slightly, to make it look more ES6-ish...

```js
const slots = [
  "09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00",
  "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00",
  "16:00 - 16:30",
  "17:00 - 17:30"
];

const optimize = (arr, delim) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, item) =>
    (([cs, ce, ps, pe]) => pe !== cs
      ? [ ...acc, ...[[ps, pe], [cs, ce]].map(p => p.join(delim)) ]
      : [ ...acc, [ ps, ce ].join(delim) ]
    )([item, acc.pop()].map(p => p.split(delim)).flat()),
    [ arr.shift() ]);


console.log(optimize(slots, ' - '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is an optimized version that splits each slot once and recombines them at the very end. This is much harder to follow.

```js
const slots = [
  "09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00",
  "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00",
  "16:00 - 16:30",
  "17:00 - 17:30"
];

const optimize = (arr, delim) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, item) =>
    ((prev, [ start, end ]) => prev.end !== start
      ? [ ...acc, prev, { start, end } ]
      : [ ...acc, { start: prev.start, end } ]
    )(acc.pop(), item.split(delim)),
    [ (([start, end]) => ({ start, end }))
      (arr.shift().split(delim)) ])
    .map(obj => Object.values(obj).join(delim));


console.log(optimize(slots, ' - '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: It is just what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got held up before I could post

This version is using objects which are easier to use subsequently

```js
const compressed = ["09:00 - 09:30", "09:30 - 10:00", "10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00", "11:30 - 12:00", "12:00 - 12:30", "12:30 - 13:00", "16:00 - 16:30", "17:00 - 17:30"].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const [start, end] = cur.split(" - ");
  if (acc.length) {
    if (acc[acc.length - 1].end === start) acc[acc.length - 1].end = end;
    else acc.push({ start, end });
  } else acc.push({ start, end });
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(compressed)
```